# Property of least upper bound. Theorem from Apostol not clear

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

From Calculus by Tom Apostol:

> DEFINITION  OF  LEAST  UPPER BOUND.
>   A  number  $B$  is  called  a  least  Upper  bound  of  a nonempty  set  $S$  if  $B$  has  the following   two   properties:
>   (a) $B$  is  an  Upper  bound for  $S$.
>   (b) No number less than $B$ is an Upper bound for $S$

THEOREM 1.32. Let $h$ be a given positive number and let $S$ be a set of real numbers.
 If $S$ has a supremum, then for some $x$ in $S$ we have $x\gt\ \sup S\space -h$

Let be the set $A=\{1\}$
$A$ is bounded above and is nonempty, therefore it has least upper bound. The least upper bound is $1$.

Now, let $h = 0,1$ $SupA - h = 0,9$ but $0,9 \notin A$ contradicting the theorem.

In the book, there is no asumption that the set should contain infinite elements or to be dense.

Can you clarify this confusion?
Thanks.

Comment: $1 > 0.9$, and clearly $1\in A$. Nowhere is said that $\sup S-h\in S$.

Comment: Thanks. I got it all wrong here. I would like to delete the post.

Answer (score 3):

If $h=0.1$, then $\sup A-h=1-0.1=0.9$. Now the theorem guarantees an $x\in A$ such that $x>\sup A-h=0.9$. And here, $x=1\in A$ fits the bill. Your mistake was assuming that the theorem guarantees an element in $A$ to be equal to $\sup A-h$.

Comment: Carlitos_30 means $h=0.9$, using the notation used in Germany (and probably also some other countries) where the decimal separator is a comma, not a point.

Comment: Yes, I understand the theorem now. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my answer.